# Cannot Clear Value of Textbox with JS

Tags: javascript

I have a web form that has a number of inputs and some javascript. I am attempting to hide certain fields based on previous selections. The code will hide the fields no problem. But I am attempting to clear any value that was entered into the fields before it is hidden.

The use case is:
The user selects a number between 1-6 in a dropdown. A corresponding number of text boxes are shown. The issue is, the user can populate all 6 textboxes then change the dropdown to 2, so 4 are hidden. The hidden fields will still hold their value.

This is the code I have tried:

```
function renderStudentFields(quantity) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        if (i <= quantity) {
            document.getElementById(`s${i}`).value = '';
            document.getElementById(`s${i}`).style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById(`s${i}`).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

I tried calling the code directly:
`document.getElementById(`s1`).value = '';`

But regardless the textbox value remains.

Any ideas of other approaches I can take with this?

Comment: can you show the html code?

Comment: document.getElementById("s"+i).value =""'; can you try this?

Comment: This code should always clear all textboxes b/c i is always <= 6.

Comment: _“But I am attempting to clear any value that was entered into the fields before it is hidden.”_ - then why are you trying to empty the value in the if branch that makes the fields _visible_, and not in the else branch where they actually get _hidden_ …?

Comment: @misorude The code doesn't fire, regardless of where I place it.

Comment: Start by showing us what you tried - [mre]. Right now you have only shown us the function, we have no idea where you even tried to call it, and therefor can’t tell what you might have done wrong either.

Answer (score 0):

I think how you are doing is correct, I just think you should move `document.getElementById(`s${i}`).value = '';` to the `else` statment.
You can check that [here](https://codepen.io/aquilesb/pen/oKvYQe?editors=1111)

```js
const changeOptions = event => {
  const { value } = event.target;

  if (value) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
      if (i <= value) {
        document.getElementById(`s${i}`).style.display = "";
      } else {
        document.getElementById(`s${i}`).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById(`s${i}`).value = "";
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
      document.getElementById(`s${i}`).style.display = "";
    }
  }
};

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("options").addEventListener("change", changeOptions);
};
```

```css
#form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="options">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
  <select>
   <form id="form">
     <label>Input 1<input type="text" id="s1" /></label>
     <label>Input 2<input type="text" id="s2" /></label>
     <label>Input 3<input type="text" id="s3" /></label>
     <label>Input 4<input type="text" id="s4" /></label>
     <label>Input 5<input type="text" id="s5" /></label>
     <label>Input 6<input type="text" id="s6" /></label>
   </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function renderStudentFields(e){
    const qty = e.target.value;
    [1,2,3,4,5,6].forEach(idx => {
        const field = document.getElementById(`s${idx}`);
        field.style.display = 'none';
        field.value = idx === qty ? field.value : '';
        if(idx <= qty){
            field.style.display = 'block';
        }
    });
}

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("boxes").addEventListener("change", renderStudentFields);
};
```

```
<div>
    <select id="boxes">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
    <select>
    <form id="form" style="display:flex;flex-direction: column;">
        <input type="text" id="s1" placeholder="s1" />
        <input type="text" id="s2" placeholder="s2" />
        <input type="text" id="s3" placeholder="s3" />
        <input type="text" id="s4" placeholder="s4" />
        <input type="text" id="s5" placeholder="s5" />
        <input type="text" id="s6" placeholder="s6" />
    </form>
</div>
```